# CSS3 Animation | Simple issue

Tags: animation, css, css-animations

I have the following CSS code :

```
@keyframes hvr_shadow
{
    from
    {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    }

    to
    {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes hvr_shadow /* Firefox */
{
    from
    {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    }

    to
    {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr_shadow /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    }

    to
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
    }
}

#gallery .fancybox
{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 138px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
}

#gallery .fancybox:hover
{
    animation: hvr_shadow 700ms;
    -moz-animation: hvr_shadow 700ms; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: hvr_shadow 700ms; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: hvr_shadow 700ms; /* Opera */
}
```

While the animation is working, after a while the shadow auto return to primary settings.

How can I keep the settings of the animation while the mouse is still hovering the image ?

Here you can find a Fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/haX8j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
-webkit-animation: hvr_shadow  700ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards;
-moz-animation: hvr_shadow  700ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards;
-o-animation: hvr_shadow  700ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards;
animation: hvr_shadow  700ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards;
```

JS Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/haX8j/1/**

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Firefox. Try my transition solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you are better off using a transition.  It's far simpler, it works with Firefox and it will fade out correctly when moving off the link:

```
.link
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);

    -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
.link:hover
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.8);
}
```

Here is a fiddle example.  I've made the shadow much bigger so you can see the effect more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/DYdZs/